# how to do this query in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How do I make this query in mongoDB?

> {
>
> > _id: "*******"
> >
> > content: "",
> >
> > comments: [
> >
> > {
> >
> > > key1: "1",
> > >
> > > key2: "2"
> >
> > },
> >
> > {
> >
> > > key1: "sdfs",
> > >
> > > key2: "sdfasdf"
> >
> > }
> >
> > ]
>
> }

For example, I use the data as below. I want to query the items in comments in condition {key1: 1, key2: 2}, and not return the whole record.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to this one

```
{ "comments.key1" : "1", "comments.key2" : "sdfasdf" }
```

You only need to use this when more than one field must be matched in the array element.

Comment: That won't work. This will match even if one comments has key1, and a *different* comment has key2. You need to use $elemMatch.

Answer (score 1):

You can query a subdocument on two fields using [`$elemMatch`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$elemMatch):

```
{ comments: { $elemMatch : { key1: 1, key2: 2 } } }
```

[You cannot return just the selected subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array). You'll get all of them. So you'll have to filter on the client side. (You can of course, exclude all other fields of the main document).

Comment: you mean even I use "$elemMatch", two subdocuments will still return ?

Comment: `$elemMatch`! I did not know about that. Yes, that would work. Updating answer.